# Dynamically adding active class to multi level sidebar menu in REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm currently creating a multilevel sidebar menu in REACT and I want to dynamically add active class to parent `<li>` when the current route is active.

The code below is how I do it for a single menu.

```
<Route
  path={this.props.to}
  exact={this.props.activeOnlyWhenExact}
  children={({ match }) => (
    <li className={match ? "active" : ""}>
      <Link to={this.props.to} activeClassName="active">
        <span className="sidebar-mini-icon">
          <i className={this.props.icon}></i></span>
          {this.props.label}
      </Link>
    </li>
  )}
/>
```

Now I wonder how I do it with multilevel menu. My menu looks like this;

[image]

As you can see, only the menu has the active class. Here's my code for the multi level menu:

```
<Route
  path={this.props.to}
  exact={this.props.activeOnlyWhenExact}
  children={({ match }) => (
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#Collapse">
      <span className="sidebar-mini-icon">
        <i className={this.props.icon}></i>
      </span>
      <span className="sidebar-normal">
        {this.props.name}
        <b className="caret"></b>
      </span>
    </a>
    <div class="collapse" id="Collapse">
       <ul className="nav">
         {this.props.children}
       </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  )}
/>
```

I'm using React Router. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I am looking for a similar answer too. Please help someone.

Comment: @Sonson Ixon, was your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [React router's nav link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink)

```
<NavLink to="/faq" activeClassName="selected">
  FAQs
</NavLink>
```

Comment: that would be for the single menu, we are looking to add class to the parent menu

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69160078/adding-class-active-to-other-parent-html-tag-with-react-router/69160230?noredirect=1#comment122236554_69160230

Comment: No it has no dependency. If you are in the route of to it will add the activeClassName. It has no parent child dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would depend on your route configuration. If you are using non-exact routes, the solution with [NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink) would be the most applicable.

Example:

**routes.jsx**

```
<Route path="/parent/child-a">
  <ChildA />
</Route>
<Route path="/parent/child-b">
  <ChildB />
</Route>
<Route path="/parent">
  <Parent />
</Route>
```

Using the above structure, `/parent/child-a` would match two routes (`/parent` and `/parent/child-a`) and the `activeClassName` prop on the `NavLink` would be applied on both HTML element.

The "challenge" with the above structure is that you are going to render `<Parent />` in all three cases.

This could be solved by using nested/child routes.

**routes.jsx**

```
<Route path="/parent">
  <NestedRoutes />
</Route>
```

**nestedRoutes.jsx**

```
<Route path="/parent/child-a" exact>
  <ChildA />
</Route>
<Route path="/parent/child-b" exact>
  <ChildB />
</Route>
```

With the updated structure above, `/parent/child-a` would match the top-level route (and as a result add the `activeClassName` to your HTML element) and *also* match the child route and add the `activeClassName` there too.

Note that if you need `/parent` to also work as a route, you need to update your nested routes as follows:

**nestedRoutes.jsx**

```
<Route path="/parent" exact>
  <Parent />
</Route>
```

From my experience, if you find yourself handling these cases manually through JavaScript or `useLocation` you might want to revisit your route configuration. `react-router` is an excellent library in its simplicity and will probably handle your case out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct would be to add `className={match ? "active" : ""}` to the parent `li`, but since you're asking about it, I'm assuming you already tried that.

You can dig around in the children's props to find out if any of them have the `match` prop (or any other prop that would indicate they're active). The following function can find a `match` prop from the children.

```
const childMatch = children => {
  if (!children) { return false }
  if (Array.isArray(children)) {
    return children.reduce(
      (acc, child) => acc || Boolean(child.props.match),
      false
    )
  }
  return Boolean(children.props.match)
}
```

You could then use it like `className={childMatch(this.props.children) ? "active" : ""}`.

If the prop you're looking for is deeper down the children tree, you can of course dig deeper. You can find grandchildren as `child.props.children`.

Comment: This didnt work. But thanks for the reply. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

##### Option 1

You can use the [`useLocation`](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/#uselocation) hook.

With the [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook, you can run a function whenever, the location changes. That way you add the class to the active parent on every location change.

But you'll need to make sure that the [`useLocation`](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/#uselocation) call is not in the same component that puts the router into the DOM.

So in the root index file, or some other component, you can have something like this

```
import { useLocation, useEffect } from "react-router-dom";

const Item = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  // Select the nav item with the active class, and add the extra class to its parent
  useMemo(() => document.querySelector(activeClassName)?.parentElement?.classList.add(activeParentClassName), [location])
  
  return (...);
}
```

---

##### Option 2

This is based on the assumption, that the routes that are grouped have an identical starting route like `/a/b/c` and `a/b/e`

A multi-level menu item should be render like this.

The label of the group should have its own `Route`, it shouldn't be exact and should have a path that makes it a parent-directory to the actual menu links

```
<li>
  <Route
    path="/a"
    children={({ match }) => (
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#Collapse" className={match ? 'active' : ''}>
          ...
      </a>
    )}
  />
```

And then the actual link items in the menu, should be exact and have a path that makes it a sub-directory to the first key

```
<ul>
  <Route
    exact
    path="/a/b"
    children={({ match }) => (
      <li className={match ? "active" : ""}>
        <Link to={this.props.to} activeClassName="active">
          {/* ... */}
        </Link>
      </li>
    )}
  />
  {/* other routes */}
</ul>
```

Comment: You don’t need to use useEffect or Dom selectors here, find out if the group and link should be active (useMemo at most which is synchronous) and derive the correct classes from it (passing as a prop if necessary) in JSX from the same or higher level in the tree. Accessing the DOM is for rare use cases and writing to the DOM in the react tree is always incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question!

If I understand correctly, the desire is to dynamically add an active class to an `li` element if the current route matches.

To do that, lets create a new componet called NavListItem. NavListItem will check to see if the current route matches its `to` prop. If it does, it will render the activeClassName. This is not too unlike the react-router-doms `NavLink` component. Except that we will render an `li` instead of a link.

NavListItem.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation, matchPath } from 'react-router-dom';

export const NavListItem = ({
  path,
  exact,
  sensitive,
  strict,
  activeClassName = 'active',
  className,
  children,
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const match = matchPath(location.pathName, {
    path: path,
    exact: exact,
    sensitive: sensitive,
    strict: strict,
  });

  const isActive = Boolean(match);

  const className = isActive ? [activeClassName, className].join(' ') : className;

  const props = {
    className: className,
    ...otherProps,
  };

  return <li {...props}>{children}</li>;
};
```

And here is the usuage with your example code.

```js
<NavListItem path={this.props.to} exact={this.props.activeOnlyWhenExact}>
  <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#Collapse">
    <span className="sidebar-mini-icon">
      <i className={this.props.icon}></i>
    </span>
    <span className="sidebar-normal">
      {this.props.name}
      <b className="caret"></b>
    </span>
  </a>
  <div class="collapse" id="Collapse">
    <ul className="nav">{this.props.children}</ul>
  </div>
</NavListItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question.
I would suggest to use React router's nav link

```
<NavLink to="/<route-name>" activeClassName=<classname>>
  Title
</NavLink>
```